# How to validate if Maven ran TestNG tests (Jenkins)

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, filenotfoundexception

I am running TestNG tests from Maven on Jenkins.
Recently we had some typo mistake inside one of the test suites and no tests were executed ('No such file or directory' message appears in the Console Output).
Jenkins job is highlighted as PASSED because there were also some JUnit tests executed in that job.
JUnit tests and TestNG tests are stored in different modules of this project and are built separately.

I was wondering if it is possible to validate somehow if at least one TestNG test was executed, and if not - fail the whole Jenkins job or maybe handle this issue differently?

Comment: Can you explain this: `JUnit tests and TestNG tests are stored in different modules of this project and are built separately.` more in detail?

Comment: My project is built from 2 java modules. Junit tests are in one of them, TestNG tests are in the second one. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I thought I will share this info as well, just in case...